# remove text before and after the text i want - PHP

Tags: php

here is my example text

```
------=_Part_564200_22135560.1319730112436
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; name=text_0.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <314>
Content-Location: text_0.txt
Content-Disposition: inline

I hate u
------=_Part_564200_22135560.1319730112436
Content-Type: image/gif; name=dottedline350.gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dottedline350.gif
Content-ID: <dottedline350.gif>
```

I need to be able to extract the "I hate u".

I know i can use explode to remove the last part after the message by doing

```
$body_content = garbled crap above;
$message_short = explode("------=_",$body_content);
echo $message_short;
```

but i need to remove the first part, along with the last part.

So, explode function above does what I need to remove the end
now i need something that says

FIND 'Content-Disposition: inline' and remove along with anything before
then
FIND '------=_' and remove along with anything after
then
Anything remaining = $message_short

echo $message_short;

will look like

I hate u

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks @Marcus

This is the code i now have and works wonderfully.

```
$body_content2 = imap_qprint(imap_body($gminbox, $email_number));
$body_content2 = strip_tags ($body_content2);    
$tmobile_body = explode("------=_", $body_content2);
$tmobile_body_short = explode("Content-Disposition: inline", $tmobile_body[1]);
$tmobile_body_complete1 = trim($tmobile_body_short[1]);
$tmobile_body_complete2 = explode("T-Mobile", $tmobile_body_complete1);
$tmobile_body_complete3 = trim($tmobile_body_complete2[1]);
```

Comment: I hate u too. But you can use a [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.info) for that, and [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead of fiddly `explode`. But do you have the complete blob maybe? Then it would be easier with [PEAR mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode).

Comment: you could try strstr on the double new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with explode and explode on "Content-Disposition: inline" here's how you can do:

```
$message_short = explode("------=_", $body_content);
$message_shorter = explode("Content-Disposition: inline", $message_short[1]);
$content = trim($message_shorter[1]);
// $content == I hate you
```

Note that this demands that the last line is `Content-Disposition: inline`

If you want to solve it using regex and use the double linebreak as a delimiter here's a codesnippet for you:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=------=_Part_564200_22135560.1319730112436)(?:.*?\s\s\s)(.*?)(?=------=_Part_564200_22135560.1319730112436)/is';
preg_match_all($pattern, $body_content, $matches);

echo($matches[1][0]);
```

Output:

```
I hate you
```

Here's a link to [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AjkJdF) with sample text.

Comment: thanks, revised my main post to show the code i used, worked perfectly.